# Selecting How Many Pages using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select how many total pages of results using `driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Last Page')`

The last page button has this:

```
<a class="btn pageJump btn-inverse hidden-xs" 
data-track="Search - Pagination - Bottom - Last Link" 
data-page="111">Last<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
```

So I'm trying to select the '111' in this case, telling me there are 111 pages of results. I can find the button using link/text, but the 111 is not shown anywhere in the properties.

Is there a way to select the data-page=111 directly?

Comment: Please share a link to that web page and the code you have already created

Comment: Using driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Last Page') finds the element, but it is not clickable and the 111 is not listed in the attribute browser in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@data-track="Search - Pagination - Bottom - Last Link"]').get_attribute('data-page')
```

This produces '111' which I can easily convert to an int for my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this. Say your last page num is stored in a variable last_page

```
xpathStr = ".//a[@data-item='"+str(last_page)+"']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathStr).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to determine how many pages are in the results so I can loop through them (set a for loop range). So I won't know the last page count ahead of time.